# How to Change Taskbar Title of Current Running Application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have delphi7 code that change application title currently running (other application, not my application).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 MyHandle: THandle;
begin
 MyHandle:=FindWindow(nil, 'Default Form Caption');
 SetWindowText(MyHandle, 'New Form Caption');
end;
```

It change the title of the windows form but the taskbar title of that form won't change. How to change the taskbar title ?

Comment: In what language is that application written ? I'm asking because if it were e.g. Delphi application, you'd (most probably) need to find its `TApplication` window and change the text of it.

Comment: @TLama : no, not delphi application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text displayed in the taskbar is the window text of the window associated with the taskbar button. So SetWindowText will do the job, provided you find the right window.

Often the window you need is the main form's window. But, as seems to be the case here, not always. For instance, older Delphi applications associate the application object's window with the taskbar button, rather than the main form's object. And other frameworks may do similar.

To find the right window, use a tool like Spy++ to study the window hierarchy of the target application. Then use FindWindow or FindWindowEx or similar to find the right window. Then call SetWindowText.

Comment: In some application SetWindowText doesn't work, why ? as in this picture http://i.imgur.com/8ZVxGrA.jpg

Comment: I explained that in the answer. You have to find the window associated with the taskbar button. You have not done so. The main window is not associated with the taskbar button for your target app. What does Spy++ tell you?

Comment: @Yusufmm, you're obviously creating some sort of warez making you an author of that application, so be a hacker. Spy++ is simple enough to understand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : i need to get Spy++ first. I will comeback to accept this answer if i find the correct window.

Comment: @TLama : i want my application cannot be analyzed

Comment: Oke, WinSpy++ help me find the correct window. Thanks to you all

Comment: @Yusufmm, never heard of [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), do you?

Comment: @whosrdaddy, never before. WinSpy++ is enough.

Comment: @Yusufmm: I was referring to your comment _"i want my application cannot be analyzed"_